# Angular 2 NgMdoule and Lazy Loaded Routing Issue

Tags: angular, routes

I am using Angular2 Rc5 in my application and stuck in routing with NgModule.

I have one module in my application called product module (lazy loaded module) with two components called productListComponenent and ProductDetailComponenet. I also have a welcome page.

When I run the application welcome page appears and from there I can navigate to a product page and from there after clicking on any product I can navigate to product detail page.

The problem I am facing is I can not directly navigate to ProductDetail page. e.g I can not browse this URL.

```
http://localhost:58248/products/1
```

My code for routing as follows.

**app.routing.ts**

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'products', loadChildren: 'app/products/product.module' }
];

export const appRoutingproviders: any[] = [];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

**product.routing.ts**

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { ProductListComponent } from './product-list.component';
import { ProductDetailComponent } from './product-detail.component';



 const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: ProductListComponent},
    { path: ':id', component: ProductDetailComponent },
    ];

export const routing = RouterModule.forChild(appRoutes);
```

when I directly browse the detail URL It gives me an error. Please refer to the attached image

[image].

Comment: How are you running the web server?  Is it a local server, such as `lite-server` or is this being served up by a different system.  It looks like whatever is serving up the site isn't loading the site from the root point (i.e. index.html) so it never loads the required JS files.

To give another example, I'm using `gulp-serve` for my project (just on the development side).  I had to put a fallback property in its configuration to load `index.html` if it didn't recognize the path.  Doing that got the site to load all the required JS before attempting to navigate to any other path.

Comment: I am using visual studio 2015 and it host the application on IIS. Also If i directly browse this URL it works fine.

`http://localhost:58248/products`

but i am only facing issue with detail page.

Comment: The routes don't seem right. Both children have the same route. Can you do a plunker with the key parts of the code so we can look at it more closely?

Comment: @DeborahK please see my updated question for  `product.routing.ts`

Comment: @DeborahK As for the plnkr, if you even run the `Angular 2 hero app` from `ROUTING & NAVIGATION`
(https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html) doc you will not be able to directly browse the hero edit/detail page.

Comment: An "unexpected token" error usually means your server is returning a 404 page instead of returning your index.html page. If you want to verify that routing still works on direct navigation, enable the hash routing using `RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { useHash: true })`

If it does work, then your server needs additional configuration to support push state which requires your server return your index.html page instead of a 404.

Comment: @Brandon Yes, it works when I enable the hash routing. So the problem is related to web server configuration for push state. But it is surprising that it works for `/products` but not for product detail view `/products/1`. And what I found when do a `/products/1` it tries to load config and system js lib underneath `products` directory. Like `products/node_module/system/..`. As I mentioned my application hosted on IIS, any idea what should be the appropriate configuration?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using RC5 make sure you use a slash in base tag not . which was belong to previous RC versions